# initizlize an array from a vector

Tags: c++

It is possible to initialise a vector from an array holding elements with the same type as vector, such as

```
double a[] ={ somevalues };
std::vector<double> vec(a, a+dimension)
```

I was wondering whether the other way around is possible or not without an explicit loop? Is that possible to initialise an array from a vector with a short cut like the one above, I guess not but let me ask ...

Comment: Vector from array, or array from vector? Your question title does not match your question body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do it at initialization, but you can use one algorithm from the STL:

```
std::vector<int> v = create_vector();
int array[100];
assert( v.size() >= 100 );
std::copy( v.begin(), v.begin()+100, array );
```

Or alternatively:

```
std::copy_n( v.begin(), 100, array );
```

The assert is to ensure that you don't go beyond the size of the vector (which would cause undefined behavior), and limiting the copies (the 100 in the expressions) so that you don't overflow the array either.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can initialize a vector from an array of the same type:

```
int a[] = {16,2,77,29};
vector<int> v (a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a) );
```

You can use std::copy to copy the vector to an array

```
copy( v.begin(), v.begin()+MAX_SIZE, a); // or v.end() if a is large enough to hold the whole vector
```

Comment: Needs a correction, but this is damn close. The second argument should be `a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to what was answered in this question is to have a pointer associated with vector's first variable (vector lays in contiguous memory):

assume following vector:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
```

our pointer:

```
int *num_arr = &v[0];
```

Advantages - instead of doubling the amount of memory by creating a new dynamic array of vec.capacity() size, you have a pointer to vec's first element, with which you can do the same thing as normal array, except that you have to pass the size, but anyway you can't estimate the size of dynamically allocated array through sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array).

calling the function:

```
print_out_array(&v[0], v.size());
```

you can have a function that prints out the "array":

```
print_out_array(const int* array, std::size_t size){
cout << "Printing out array:" << endl; 
    for (int i=0; i != size; ++i){
       cout << "i: " << i << ", value: " << array[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

See, in that function array[i] works just like array, no copies involved, no overhead in copying, no new memory is allocated - all good! :)

But you have to be careful if the vector is empty though. If v.size() is zero then &v[0] attempts to produce a pointer to something that doesn't exist - undefined behaviour.
Safer way:

```
if(!v.empty()){
  print_array(&v[0],v.size());
}
```

But be careful with strings though... they are completely different beasts...

To get full information about that matter have a look in Scott Meyer's Effective STL Item 16. Know how to pass vector and string data to legacy APIs.

Answer (score -2):

No. You can use

```
double a[] = { v[0], v[1], ... };
```

but easier you cannot get.

Comment: @downvoters Keep in mind that using `std::copy` is not initialization, but assignment. Although the OP surely is not that pedantic and `std::copy` is what he wants, this is still no reason for downvoting.